# AUCTeX inverse search with region or buffer compilation

Tags: emacs, auctex, viewers

I have inverse search working great with single-file documents with Zathura. Unfortunately, things break down when I try to do inverse search when viewing a region of my document, or a buffer in the case of multifile documents.

AUCTeX compiles the desired region (`C-c C-r`) or buffer (`C-c C-b`) by copying it to a file called `_region_.tex`, along with the preamble of the main document. However, when I try to do inverse search on the resulting PDF, rather than getting sent to the original source file, I get sent to `_region_.tex`. I've been burned by accidentally editing that file instead of the desired source file, and then loosing those changes.

How can I get inverse search to work in this case? Here is the "View" command AUCTeX uses.

`zathura  --synctex-forward 482:0:source.tex -x "emacsclient +%{line} %{input}"  _region_.pdf`

I am using AUCTeX 12.1.2 under emacs 25.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue annoyed me for a while too so I finally tried to resolve it by writing the following elisp codes. The function below lets us to go back to the original buffer from the region buffer matching the position.

```
(defun my-LaTeX-switch-from-region-buffer-to-original ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((line (line-number-at-pos))
        (col (current-column))
        number-of-preamble-lines
        offset)
    (save-excursion
      (when (re-search-backward "!offset(\\([---0-9]+\\))" nil t)
        (setq offset (string-to-number (match-string-no-properties 1)))
        (setq number-of-preamble-lines (+ (line-number-at-pos) 1))))
    (switch-to-buffer TeX-region-orig-buffer)
    (if (buffer-narrowed-p)
        (progn
          (beginning-of-buffer)
          (forward-line (- line number-of-preamble-lines))
          (move-to-column col))
      (goto-line (+ offset line))
      (move-to-column col))))
```

Then this function is added to the hook that runs after returning the focus to Emacs by the PDF viewer through the inverse-search functionality:

```
(add-function
 :after after-focus-change-function
 (lambda ()
   (if (and (frame-focus-state)
            (string-equal
             TeX-region
             (file-name-sans-extension
          (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)))))
       (my-LaTeX-switch-from-region-buffer-to-original))))
```